# __unicode__(self) for python3 and Django1.8 not working

Tags: django, python-3.x, web

use python3 and Django1.8 admin.py to manage DB:

```
  class Employee(models.Model):

       name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

       sex = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=sex_choices)

       def __unicode__(self):

           return self.name
```

i want return object's name,so i use `__unicode__(self)` return `self.name`

but result：
[image]

it's only show object ,not the name!!!!

what should i do??

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe, in python 3 with django you need to define __str__() instead of __unicode__().

I found information about this in section "__str__() and  __unicode__() methods" [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/python3/#str-and-unicode-methods).